# (WPF) Popup with a TabItem Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, togglebutton

I currently have an application that uses a ToggleButton/Popup feature and it all works as expected, but I wanted to see if there's a way (either through control templates or custom controls) that allows the toggle button to be included as part of the popup window.

The effect I'm going for is similar to the standard TabControl/TabItem layout but instead the ToggleButton would replace the header of the TabItem and the Popup would serve as it's content.

In the end, I want to have the Popup window display to the immediate right side of the ToggleButton and have one continuous border that wraps around the outside edges of the ToggleButton and the outside edges of the Popup window with no border inbetween.  The final appearance would show no separation between the two controls, and the user would perceive the ToggleButton and the Popup as a single control object.

I was thinking it might be possible to edit a template of a standard TabItem and have it's content property display as a popup, but haven't tried it yet.

Let me know if you think this is the way to go or if there's any other potential solutions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything in WPF can be done in multiple ways. The same is true with your goal.

If you plan on reusing this control in multiple places, I would suggest building it as a custom control. I build custom controls and UI libraries for a living, so I am a bit biased.

I would build a custom control that inherits from `HeaderedContentControl`. The `Header` property is the content of your `ToggleButton`, and the `Content` property would be the content of your `Popup`. Since you own the `ControlTemplate` and code, you can make it look and function exactly how you need it to with no compromises.